# connecting openldap with phpldapadmin

Tags: openldap, phpldapadmin

I have 3 servers meant for openldap, phpldapadmin and client access. i have done phpldapadmin installation and i can access it through server 3 in browser http://example.local/ldapadmin

and in server 1 (openldap) i have open ldap protocol, port 389/tcp and install ldap:

```
yum install -y openldap openldap-clients openldap-servers
chkconfig slapd on
systemctl enable slapd
systemctl start slapd
```

but when i try to login it said:

> can't contact ldap server (-1) for user

anyone knows how to configure openldap so it can use/manage by phpldapadmin remotely?

what configuration missing?

environment: centos 7

Thank you,
AnD

Answer (score 1):

In order for this to work you have to make some modifications, after you have installed openldap and phplapadmin.

Luckily, you have centos 7 !! Just go follow these links

- For Openldap, you must configure your ldap, follow this [link](https://www.server-world.info/en/note?os=CentOS_7&p=openldap&f=1)
- For phpldapadmin, follow this [link](https://www.server-world.info/en/note?os=CentOS_7&p=openldap&f=7)

Answer (score 0):

In /etc/phpldapadmin you will find a config.php file.  In this file you specify the servers with the $server variable like this:
$servers->setValue('server','host','name_or_ip_of_your_server');

If the directory is missing you have not installed phpldapadmin correctly, to do that run:
sudo apt-get install phpldapadmin 
or 
sudo yum install phpldapadmin

Answer (score 0):

First check if openldap is accessible from the machine where phpldapadmin is installed using below command

```
telnet <ip-of-openldap-machine> 389
```

If you find port opened check below configuration settings from phpldapadmin config file. You will find config file under */etc/phpldapadmin/config.php*

```
$servers->setValue('server','host','127.0.0.1');
$servers->setValue('server','base',array('dc=example,dc=com'));
$servers->setValue('login','bind_id','cn=admin,dc=example,dc=com');
```

This should do the work incase of vanilla installation of openldap server.